# How to intercept Stacked notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am well familiar with the concept of [stacked notification](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html) .

The mobile doesn't show non-summary notifications if there is a corresponding summary notification. But if there is no summary notification, non-summary notifications are displayed

I am listening to every notification posted by NotificationListenerService introduced in Kitkat. I intercept and display every notification text as they arrive.

Problem is when stacked notifications arrive, I get callbacks for both groupSummary and non-summary notifications. If I have to decide if a non-summary should be displayed, I have to check every other notification for a summary.

How do I replicate the behaviour of mobile without going through the list of all present notifications repeatedly, that is, in less than O(n^2) complexity? Or does Android source code also do it the same complex way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I devised a method myself with complexity < O(n^2). Guess I didn't think about using better data structures. Here's the function . Feel free to point out mistakes if any.

```
private ArrayList<StatusBarNotification> cleanseNonSummary(ArrayList<StatusBarNotification> notifications) throws Exception{
    Set<String> groupSet = new HashSet<>();

    //first run : add all summary notification keys to unique set
    for(StatusBarNotification sbn : notifications){

        if(NotificationCompat.isGroupSummary(sbn.getNotification()))
            groupSet.add(NotificationCompat.getGroup(sbn.getNotification()));
    }

    //second run : remove all non summary notifications whose key matches with set elements
    for(int i=0; i<notifications.size(); i++) {
        StatusBarNotification sbn = notifications.get(i);

        if (!NotificationCompat.isGroupSummary(sbn.getNotification())) {
            String groupId = NotificationCompat.getGroup(sbn.getNotification());

            if (groupId != null && groupSet.contains(groupId))
                notifications.remove(i--);
                //decrement counter if an element is removed
        }
    }

    return notifications;
}
```